# Cannot upload an .apk file to the market

Tags: android, google-play, apk, manifest

I have developed a new application for Android and my application is completed. It doesn't have any errors except for a few (2) harmless warnings. I created an .apk package using the tools available in ECLIPSE. It created a key and an .apk file. Created  all right. **BUT when I upload the .apk file I get an error telling that I cannot use the following in front of the package name :[com.android,com.goolge,android,com.example]**

Below is my manifest details

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="android.Scheduler"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />  
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />  
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label=".SchedulerActivity" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".SchedulerActivity" >

        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
          <activity android:name=".addSubject"/>
           <activity android:name=".Assignment"/>
           <activity android:name=".CameraTake" android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>


            <activity android:name=".view_details"/>
            <activity android:name=".about"/>
            <activity android:name=".help"/>
               <activity android:name=".MyAlarmService"/>
                <activity android:name=".Assignment_view"/>
               <receiver android:name=".MyAlarmService" />



</application>
```

I tried some methods that are explained in here but it didn't work. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have choosen incorrect package name "android.Scheduler", just change your package name.

For eg. if your name is "ravi" then choose package name something like this-

"com.ravi.scheduler".

Steps change package name (eclipse):-

Under your project folder just go to "src" then here you found "android.Scheduler" right click on it, choose "Refactor" -> "rename" & then write your desired package name like "com.ravi.scheduler" & click OK.

Now Rebuild/Run your project & then do application signing.

Now you are ready to upload your app to Google Play.

Comment: Thanks This solved my problem now i can upload to markets Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It is because of

```
package="android.Scheduler"
```

that you are getting this problem.

Notice in your file browser that you probably have src > android > scheduler

you cannot have android there.

all I can think of for a quick fix, is start a new project FROM that one, and in the setup set the package name to com.something.yourappname, but where "something" is do not include "google" or "android"